# Compare 2 pandas dataframe with different lengths and get the column name which has changed value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 dataframes of unequal length. Some records can be present in both and some might be only be there in 1 dataframe.

```
data = [['1001', 4573, 'Test1'], ['1002', 4574, 'Test2'], ['1003', 4575, 'Test3']]
 
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['id', 'addressid','address'])

data = [['1001', 4573, 'Test1'], ['1002', 4574, 'Test22']]
 
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['id', 'addressid','address'])
```

I need a best approach to get the difference column name. ie, here id 1002's address changed from Address2 to Address22, so I need the column name to be returned as output.

Expected Output : [Address]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you set the `id` column as the index of your two dataframes you can compare values (like a merge):

```
# set id as index
df1 = df1.set_index('id')
df2 = df2.set_index('id')

# find inner join of index and columns
rows = df1.index.intersection(df2.index)
cols = df1.columns.intersection(df2.columns)

# get columns where at least one value is different
out = df2.loc[rows, cols].ne(df1.loc[rows, cols]).any() \
         .loc[lambda x: x].index.tolist()
print(out)

# Output
['address']
```

Comment: This answer is much simpler and would be preferable to mine, if you only want the list of columns that had exhibited changes, regardless of how  many records or which records had changes.  Nice, concise answer, @Corralien.

Comment: And if you did want to see a matrix of which columns changed for which records, you could just leave the output at:  
    out = df2.loc[rows, cols].ne(df1.loc[rows, cols]).

Comment: @BioData41. You are totally right.

Comment: @Corralien : Thanks a lot, this was exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 3):

Here is a generalized approach that is not specific to columns names, assumes multiple columns may have changed, and multiple records may have changed:

Note that I set "id" as the index, so that I've have some identity basis on which to compare records that would be expected to be the same entity.

This does not just print a single column name that changed for a single record, but will generate a dataframe/table that contains all the records that had been changed, and shows the column name (or list of names) that changed.

```
data = [['1001', 4573, 'Test1'], ['1002', 4574, 'Test2'], ['1003', 4575, 'Test3']]
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['id', 'addressid','address'])
data = [['1001', 4573, 'Test1'], ['1002', 4574, 'Test22']]
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['id', 'addressid','address'])


def getColChangedName(row):
    colsChanged = []
    for c in df1.columns.values:
        if row[c+"_diff"] == True:
            colsChanged.append(c)
    return ", ".join(colsChanged)


df1 = df1.set_index("id")
df2 = df2.set_index("id")

diffs = df1.merge(df2, left_index=True, right_index=True, suffixes=('_old', '_new'))

diff_cols = [c+"_diff" for c in df1.columns.values]

for c in df1.columns.values:
    diffs[c+"_diff"] = diffs[c+"_old"] != diffs[c+"_new"]
    
diffs["Record_Changed"] = diffs[diff_cols].sum(axis=1)/len(diff_cols) > 0


diffs = diffs[diffs["Record_Changed"] == 1]
diffs["Cols_Changed"] = diffs.apply(lambda row: getColChangedName(row), axis=1)

diffs.head()
```

The resulting diffs DataFrame looks like this on the test data:

[image]

And, more simply, if you just want the list of columns changed for each record:

```
print(diffs[["Cols_Changed"]])

     Cols_Changed
id               
1002      address
```

Comment: There is one problem. When the change is that a new row was added it results in this error: ValueError: Expected a 1D array, got an array with shape (0, 7)
How can this be fixed?